# Npgsql 4.x support for System.Transactions.TransactionsScope not working?

Tags: c#, postgresql, transactions, npgsql

We've got a web-based, multi-tiered eHealth system platform that uses a class/object hierarchy. As an example, a "patient clinic visit" object may consist of multiple diagnosis objects, multiple medication objects, multiple observation objects, laboratory test objects and so on. Database transactions are handled using the .NET System.Transactions.TransactionScope.

When persisting data into the database each nested object in the hierarchy:

1. instantiates a TransactionScope (with the default transaction
   required option)
2. instantiates an NpgsqlConnection connection
3. does its own SQL and
4. sets transactionsScope.Complete(), if all went well

To simplify, objects in the object hierarchy are doing like the code sample below:

```
void RootMethod()
{
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        /* Perform transactional work here */
        SomeMethod();
        AnotherMethod();

        scope.Complete();
    }
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using(NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open()
            /* Perform transactional work here */
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}

void AnotherMethod()
{
    using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using(NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open()
            /* Perform transactional work here */
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Program code that is encapsulated in "using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {...}" code blocks gets enlisted in the same transaction fine on Oracle (with an db Oracle driver) but with Npgsql on Postgres **separate transactions would appear to get generated** instead of one transaction.

As a result, transactions on Postgres fail because of foreign key constraints - data cannot be persisted in child tables as the separate transactions that get created don't see data inserted in parent tables (in separate transaction) before the data is commited by parent objects.

We've got Enlist=true in the Npgsql connectString and the server parameter max_prepared_transactions set to a bigger number than 0 value on our Postgres server.

The Npgsql driver versions we've tested are 4.0.7 and 4.1.2. The Postgres server version in our devt environment is version 10.

Npgsql documentation https://www.npgsql.org/doc/transactions.html says System.Transactions.TransactionScope is supported (and has been since v3.3), as do other Npgsql related answers we've search for on StackOverflow.

At first glance the [Npgsql unit tests](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/7ca02e99977deab9c0dafc142e4ddd3f55eb995e/test/Npgsql.Tests/SystemTransactionTests.cs) would appear to use one database connection in transactional unit tests.

QUESTIONS:

- are multiple TransactionScopes and multiple participating database connections as per TransactionScope implementation guidelines (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope) supported on Npgsql?
- Anything obvious we are missing here?

As stated above, with Npgsql 4.x each opened database connection in "using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {...}" code block would appear to generate a new transaction instead of enlisting in one and the same transaction.

Comment: Running the code you provide above with the latest Npgsql version triggers only one transaction, as shown in the PG logs; [as detailed in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope#voting-inside-a-nested-scope), your nested scopes in SomeMethod and AnotherMethod don't actually create a transaction - they simply join the root scope in RootMethod, and their calls to Complete are simply votes to commit.

Comment: Note that you should *not* need to set max_prepared_transactions to non-zero: the code sample above should work without escalating to a distributed transaction. This is because you only have a single connection open in the (root) transaction scope at a given point in time, and so Npgsql internally reuses the same physical connection. If you had two connections open at the same time, escalation to a distributed transaction would occur (and then we're in quite a different world).

Comment: Try to recheck why you think that multiple database transactions are actually being created.

Comment: Thank you Shay, this was most helpful - pointed us to the issue in our code. My simplified code illustration above was not quite accurate (my bad): it appears we did open an NpgsqlConnection in the root TransactionScope and had not closed that connection before an inner TransactionScope opened a second NpgsqlConnection - effectively resulting in a distributed (two separate) transaction(s), which was unintentional. Hence separate blocks of program code did not see each others work while on the same database (on Oracle they did). @shay-rojansky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One needs to close an NpgsqlConnection opened in an outer TransactionScope before opening a second NpgsqlConnection in an inner TransactionScope (to allow Npgsql to internally reuse the same physical connection, without escalation to a distributed transaction to occur).